# Is there a way to recover lost CA and TLS certs?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Long story short, I have a production environment of Hyperledger Fabric (and HL FireFly) where I have lost all authentication certs and TLS certs for the CAs themselves, Peers, Orderers, users, etc. Basically, I didn't realize the tmp folder in linux removes things from it. I followed the outline provided in the documentation and turns out, all the certs, msps, etc, where removed from the tmp folder on the host machine. Because the mount in the docker containers is tied to this, the certs where removed from the containers as well. I still have the fabric-ca-server.db for the orderer org and the main org for some reason. Is there any way to recover these certs? The network is still operating as normal, seemingly. But I know they won't start back up if I turn them off.

I have tried shutting down the CAs and restarting them. I then just enroll everything again. This then breaks the comms between the nodes because the channel was initialized with TLS certs from a "different" CA. It is the same CA, but it has to regenerate it's own certs again, so they are then different.

Can I do anything with the network at this point? I have tried everything I can think of.

Is there a way to create a new channel and merge the current ledge in the broken one onto the new channel? I can't seem to access the channel config to update that or anything.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. I can provide more details if anyone is willing to help me or knows any answers. Thank you all so much.

Notes - this is not using testnet and I do not use cryptogen for anything.

Comment: I think the only possibility would be deleted file recovery. There's software for this but it's hit or miss at the best of times and you're running in a small, dynamic environment making matters worse. (Any drive activity, especially restarting, makes things worse when it comes to file recovery.) Given your description, it's pretty unlikely anything is left. If you or your host make backups, it would worth perusing those.